# Usage-specific serialization for complex type in Dictionary with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, complextype

I have a class

```
public class MyValue 
{
    public String Prop1 { get; set; }
    public String Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

which I am both using as a type for a normal Property as well as a Dictionary key.

What I need is a way so that when this class is used as a Property, it is serialized as

```
{"Prop1":"foo","Prop2":"bar"}
```

but when it is used as a Dictionary key, it is serialized in a way that JSON.Net is able to deserialize it properly.

When adding a ToString() method to MyValue, I am able to create a text representation (non-JSON) that allows the usage as Dictionary key but unfortunately, I am not able to deserialize it afterwards. Even adding a JsonConverter for MyValue did not help because it seems to be unable to handle non-JSON as source format (and additionally, when serialized as a property, it IS json, so the converter would need to handle both somehow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you could do is serialize and deserialize your dictionary in a proxy `KeyValuePair<string, string>` array, like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyContainer
{
    public MyContainer() {
        this.Dictionary = new Dictionary<MyValue, int>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public MyValue MyValue { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Dictionary<MyValue, int> Dictionary { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="Dictionary")]
    private KeyValuePair<MyValue, int> [] SerializedDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if (Dictionary == null)
                return null;
            return Dictionary.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                Dictionary = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary = value.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Here I'm using the `DataContract` attributes, but I could just as easily have used `[JsonIgnore]` and `[JsonProperty("Dictionary")]`)

So, to test this (and assuming that you have properly overridden `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` on `MyValue`, which you need to do in order to use it as a dictionary key), I did the following:

```
public static class TestDictionaryJson
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<MyValue, int>();
        dict[(new MyValue("A", "A"))] = 1;
        dict[(new MyValue("B", "B"))] = 2;

        var myContainer = new MyContainer() { MyValue = new MyValue("A Property", "At the top level"), Dictionary = dict };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myContainer, Formatting.Indented);

        Debug.WriteLine(json);

        try
        {
            var newContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyContainer>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString()); // No assert - no exception is thrown.
        }

        try
        {
            var dictjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
            Debug.WriteLine(dictjson);
            var newDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<MyValue, int>>(dictjson);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Caught expected exception deserializing dictionary directly: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Sure enough, there was no exception deserializing the container, but there *was* deserializing the dictionary directly.  And the following JSON was created for the container:

```
{
  "MyValue": {
    "Prop1": "A Property",
    "Prop2": "At the top level"
  },
  "Dictionary": [
    {
      "Key": {
        "Prop1": "A",
        "Prop2": "A"
      },
      "Value": 1
    },
    {
      "Key": {
        "Prop1": "B",
        "Prop2": "B"
      },
      "Value": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Is that what you want?

**Update**

Or, if you don't like the proxy arrays, you could apply the following `JsonConverterAttribute` to each and every `Dictionary` property to get the same result:

```
public class MyContainer
{
    public MyContainer()
    {
        this.Dictionary = new Dictionary<MyValue, int>();
    }

    public MyValue MyValue { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryToArrayConverter<MyValue, int>))]
    public Dictionary<MyValue, int> Dictionary { get; set; }
}

public class DictionaryToArrayConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] pairs;

        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            pairs = token.ToObject<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]>(serializer);
        }
        else
        {
            JArray array = new JArray();
            array.Add(token);
            pairs = token.ToObject<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]>(serializer);
        }
        if (pairs == null)
            return null;
        return pairs.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return;
        var pairs = ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)value).ToArray();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, pairs);
    }
}
```

**Update**

As an alternative, you could seal your `MyValue` class and attach an appropriate [`TypeConverterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for converting from & to a string.  JSON.Net will pick this up and use it both for dictionary keys and properties.  This solution is simpler in that it's a global solution so you don't need to use proxy arrays or converter properties for each and every dictionary, however the JSON created for your `MyValue` properties isn't quite what you require.

Thus:

```
public class MyValueConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            // Cannot do JsonConvert.DeserializeObject here because it will cause a stackoverflow exception.
            using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader((string)value)))
            {
                JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
                if (item == null)
                    return null;
                MyValue myValue = new MyValue();
                var prop1 = item["Prop1"];
                if (prop1 != null)
                    myValue.Prop1 = prop1.ToString();
                var prop2 = item["Prop2"];
                if (prop2 != null)
                    myValue.Prop2 = prop2.ToString();
                return myValue;
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            MyValue myValue = (MyValue)value;

            // Cannot do JsonConvert.SerializeObject here because it will cause a stackoverflow exception.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
                jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Prop1");
                jsonWriter.WriteValue(myValue.Prop1);
                jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Prop2");
                jsonWriter.WriteValue(myValue.Prop2);
                jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(MyValueConverter))]
public class MyValue
{
    public MyValue()
    {
    }

    public MyValue(string prop1, string prop2)
    {
        this.Prop1 = prop1;
        this.Prop2 = prop2;
    }

    public String Prop1 { get; set; }
    public String Prop2 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        else if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return false;
        if (GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;
        var other = (MyValue)obj;
        return Prop1 == other.Prop1 && Prop2 == other.Prop2;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            uint code = 0;
            if (Prop1 != null)
                code ^= (uint)Prop1.GetHashCode();
            code = (code << 16) | (code >> 16);
            if (Prop2 != null)
                code ^= (uint)Prop2.GetHashCode();
            return (int)code;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType()).ConvertToString(this);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyValue first, MyValue second)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(first, null))
            return ReferenceEquals(second, null);
        return first.Equals(second);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyValue first, MyValue second)
    {
        return !(first == second);
    }
}
```

Properties and dictionaries using this class can now be serialized without the use of any proxy arrays.  For instance, serializing and deserializing the following:

```
public class MyContainer
{
    public MyContainer()
    {
        this.Dictionary = new Dictionary<MyValue, int>();
    }

    public MyValue MyValue { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<MyValue, int> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Gives the following JSON when serialized:

```
{
  "MyValue": "{\"Prop1\":\"A Property\",\"Prop2\":\"At the top level\"}",
  "Dictionary": {
    "{\"Prop1\":\"A\",\"Prop2\":\"A\"}": 1,
    "{\"Prop1\":\"B\",\"Prop2\":\"B\"}": 2
  }
}
```

(the quotes are escaped since they are embedded in the JSON, not part of the JSON.)

**Late Update - creating a generic `TypeConverter` for dictionary keys**

It's possible to create a generic `TypeConverter` that works for any generically specified type by using an appropriate [contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm):

```
public class NoTypeConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly Type type;

    public NoTypeConverterContractResolver(Type type)
        : base()
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type == typeof(string) || type.IsPrimitive)
            throw new ArgumentException("type == typeof(string) || type.IsPrimitive");
        this.type = type;
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            // Replaces JsonStringContract for the specified type.
            var contract = this.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
            return contract;
        }
        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}

public class GenericJsonTypeConverter<T> : TypeConverter
{
    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
    static NoTypeConverterContractResolver contractResolver;

    static NoTypeConverterContractResolver ContractResolver
    {
        get
        {
            if (contractResolver == null)
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref contractResolver, new NoTypeConverterContractResolver(typeof(T)), null);
            return contractResolver;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader((string)value)))
            {
                var obj = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = ContractResolver }).Deserialize<T>(reader);
                return obj;
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = ContractResolver }).Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your class as follows:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(GenericJsonTypeConverter<MyValue>))]
public class MyValue
{

}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, awesome answer! I chose the route with DictionaryToArrayConverter and, though I only tested it quickly, seems to work perfectly :)