# How to return Dictionary<complexType,int> with WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm providing a WebApi 2 endpoint that is done in this way:

My controller is simply:

```
 public IDictionary<MyClass, int> GetMyClasses(string id)
 {
    Dictionary<MyClasses, int> sample = new Dictionary<MyClasses, int>();

    sample.Add(new MyClasses()
    {
       Property1 = "aaa",
       Property2 = 5,
       Property3 = 8
    },10);

    return sample;
 }
```

The structure of MyClass is:

```
public class MyClass
{
   string Property1 {get;set;}
   int Property2 {get;set;}
   int Property3 {get;set;}
}
```

When I run my webservice, the helper webpage shows me that the expected outputs are:

```
{ "MyNamespace.MyProject.MyClass": 1 }
```

On the other hand the xml sample is what I'd like (except that I want the json, not the xml):

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfMyClassintl85fHlC_P xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <KeyValueOfMyClassintl85fHlC_P>
    <Key xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace.MyProject.MyClass">
      <d3p1:Property1>sample string 4</d3p1:Property1>
      <d3p1:Property2>8</d3p1:Property2>
      <d3p1:Property3>5</d3p1:Property3>
    </Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </KeyValueOfMyClassintl85fHlC_P>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfMyClassintl85fHlC_P >
```

I also ran the endpoint with Postman and it confirms that the returned value is the one previewed by the WebApi out of the box page.

Why the json is "wrong" and the xml is well done (I mean that contains all the data)?

**UPDATED:**

I expected MyClass serialized in json like this:

```
{
  "Property1": "sample string 4",
  "Property2": 8,
  "Property3": 5
}
```

This should be the structure of the key of my dictionary, as it is in the xml representation.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of JSON would you expect this to produce?

Comment: You clarified how you'd expect MyClass to be serialized, but how would you expect an `IDictionary<MyClass,int>` to be serialized?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior the serialization that I wrote instead of "MyNamespace.MyProject.MyClass".
Do you think it will _corrupt_ the json?

Comment: WebApi 2 [uses Json.NET as its JSON formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).  By default Json.NET [can only serialize a dictionary whose keys can be converted to a string](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm).  See here for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332723/usage-specific-serialization-for-complex-type-in-dictionary-with-json-net

Comment: @ff8mania: I was hoping that you could clarify what you wanted the return value to look like so that I could provide just the answer that you were looking for, instead of three separate answers and an explanation of what circumstance you'd use each in. If you'd taken a moment to write out the whole JSON object you're envisioning, you'd have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 7):

This is kind of hacky, but I had success by converting the Dictionary to a List object before running it through JsonConvert.  Check it out:

```
IDictionary<MyClass,int> dict = new Dictionary<MyClass, int>();
MyClass classy = new MyClass() { value = value };
dict.Add(classy, 5);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict); //<--- Returns [{MyClass: 5}], boo
```

Whereas . . .

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict.ToList()); //<--- Returns [{Key: blah blah blah, Value: 5}], nice
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

What does your Controller look like?  The endpoint should look something like this:

```
[Route("")] 
public IHttpActionResult Get() 
{ 
    IDictionary<MyClass, int> resource = new Dictionary<MyClass, int> 
    {
        { new MyClass {Property1="1", Property2=2, Property3=3}, 0 },
        { new MyClass {Property1="11", Property2=22, Property3=33}, 1 },
    };

    return Ok(resource); 
}
```

If you're still having JSON serialization issues after that, you can configure the default `JsonFormatter` type in Web API: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;`.  See [the ASP.NET Web API Serialization Documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_media_type_formatter) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Typically dictionaries are used to produce more dynamic JSON objects, by using the Key/Value pairs as name/value pairs on a JavaScript object. But a JSON object cannot use another JSON object as its key. For example, the following syntax is not valid:

```
{
    {"Property1": "sample string 4",... } : 1,
    {"Property1": "sample string 5",... } : 2,
}
```

So you'll need to decide exactly how you want this information represented in JSON. Are you thinking of it as an array of Key/Value objects?

```
[ 
    { Key: {"Property1": "sample string 4",...}, Value: 1 },
    { Key: {"Property1": "sample string 5",...}, Value: 2 },
]
```

In that case, return a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` from your method, via `dict.ToList()`.

Do your keys and values have meanings? Perhaps you should create a class to represent each item with custom property names, via `dict.Select(kvp => new MyDto { MyClass = kvp.Key, Foo = kvp.Value }).ToList()`:

```
[ 
    { MyClass: {"Property1": "sample string 4",...}, Foo: 1 },
    { MyClass: {"Property1": "sample string 5",...}, Foo: 2 },
]
```

Do you want to stick with objects, but have the left-hand side be a string representation of your class? You can do this by implementing the `ToString()` method on MyClass:

```
{ 
    "sample string 4|8|5": 1, 
    "sample string 5|6|7": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to explain.
Just look at the example.

```cs
[HttpGet("CountUserTasksNumberInProject/{userId}")]
public ActionResult<ICollection<KeyValuePair<ProjectDTO, int>>> 
ReadCountUserTasksNumberInProject(int userId)
{
    Dictionary<ProjectDTO, int> result = _service.CountUserTasksNumberInProject(userId);

    if (result == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {                
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "key": {
      "id": 0,
      "authorId": 0,
      "teamId": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "deadline": "2022-07-14T10:17:12.260Z",
      "createdAt": "2022-07-14T10:17:12.260Z"
    },
    "value": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: You'd better to exaplain your codes.