# Serialize and Deserialize Dictionary<int, int> between REST services in Web API

Tags: c#, parsing, dictionary, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I have a `Web API` action method that returns a `Dictionary<int, int>` as response:

```
[HttpPost("PostStats")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostStats([FromBody]StatsBody body)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> myDic= new Dictionary<int, int>();
    ... //Do something with body and myDic
    return Ok(myDic);
}
```

The method is called through a `HttpClient`:

```
StatsBody stats = GetStatsBody();
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ROOT_ENDPOINT) })
{
    // Serializes the content to be sent to the REST service
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stats), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    // Sends the request to the REST service
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URL, content);
    // Gets the response as string
    string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //Deserialize the response into a a Dictionary<int, int>
        myDic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, int>>(output);
    }
    else
        return BadRequest(output);
}
```

the instruction `myDic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, int>>(output)` gives an exception since it is unable to deserialize the object.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"0":562,"1":563,"2":564}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]'. 

System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Int32].
```

Even if I use `Dictionary<string, int>` or `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` I get an exception. If I inspect the variable `output`, its content is in this format:

```
"{\"0\":565,\"1\":566,\"2\":567}"
```

which is not indeed a valid JSON format. The only was I can get a correct deserialization is by using:

```
string temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(output);
myDic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, int>>(temp);
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I obtain a more clear solution?

PS:

If I use a `Typescript` client and then `JSON.parse` to parse the response into an associative array (basically a dictionary), I have no issues.

Comment: Your debugger is escaping the string as expected.  There's nothing wrong with `output`

Comment: I think that could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172973/how-to-return-dictionarycomplextype-int-with-webapi

Comment: I think your content has been double serialized so check once if that happens and could you please show which exception occurred during deserialization?

Comment: @k.explorer, thanks, I tried that solution already with no success.

Comment: @er-mfahhgk thanks that's a possibility, it seems strange since it is an exchange of data within the same framework. I edited my question with the exception details

Comment: Let me try this at my end...

Comment: When you call the API Method what does it actually return? `{"0":565,"1":566,"2":567}` or `"{\"0\":565,\"1\":566,\"2\":567}"`? Or something else? (and I mean do this through something like curl or postman that will show you the raw response not interpreted by something like .net as you have above). The reason for the check being to see whether your problem lies in your API or your consuming code. Both look ok from what you've shown so we need to narrow down what code we should be focussing on...

Comment: @CiccioMiami, I'd tried your `output` string to deserialize into `Dictionary<int, int>` or `Dictionary<string, int>` or `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` and it successfully deserialized into all above dictionaries. so I have also questioned why your `output` string not deserialised at your end?

Comment: @CiccioMiami, I'll add answer for you to catch up all the things clearly.