# WEB API serialization of Dictionary composite Key

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API service. My class is as follows

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<MyClass, List<MyClass>> MyDataDictionary { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I am facing problem with serialization of dictionary **Key**, which is composite type **MyClass**. When WebAPI returns MyClass instance, I see that dictionary key are not serialised, instead its type (*MyNamespace.MyClass*) is present there.

```
MyClassObj.MyDataDictionary.Add(new MyClass("1", "Name1") , List);
```

Always List is serialized. why not Key Object, how to fix it?

```
{  
   "Id":2,"Name":"Unknown",

   "MyDataDictionary":{  
      "*MyNamespace.MyClass*":[  
         {  
            "Id":2, "Name":"Th/Abd",
            "MyDataDictionary ":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect them to be serialized in a JSON or even XML structure? Please provide an example of the result you are expecting after the serialization and show us what you are getting instead.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27043792/6017401

Comment: As @ChrisS indicates, this is known limitation of Json.NET.  See [Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504245).  For additional workarounds, see [Usage-specific serialization for complex type in Dictionary with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332723)