# List of Dictionaries doesn't deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I'm creating a WCF service that will accept data that looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Payload
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Dictionary<string,string>> Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I submit this data:

```
{"Prop1":"A","Prop2":"B","Prop3":[{"Prop4":"D","Prop5":"E"},{"Prop6":"F","Prop7":"G"}]}
```

The deserialized object has `Prop1` and `Prop2` filled out correctly, and `Prop3` contains two `Dictionary` objects - but both `Dictionaries` are empty.

I also changed Prop3 to use an internal class:

```
public List<PayloadData> Prop3 { get; set; }

[DataContract]
public class PayloadData : ISerializable, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string,string> _dict;

    public PayloadData()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }

    ...
}
```

This had the same result. I also tried making the `PayloadData` class implement both `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` and `IDictionary<string,string>` with no luck.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510185/how-to-serialize-dictionarystring-string-through-wcf

Comment: The problem is that WCF uses `DataContractJsonSerializer`, and the latter serializes dictionaries as arrays, not objects.  See [Any way to make DataContractJsonSerializer serialize Dictionaries properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559991).  While it is possible to override this behavior in WCF, it is quite difficult.  See for instance [Using Custom WCF Body Deserialization without changing URI Template Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554997).

Comment: To work around this incompatibility on the client side, you could use `DictionaryToArrayConverter<TKey, TValue>` from [Usage-specific serialization for complex type in Dictionary with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332723).  And for deserialization on the Json.NET side, see [Newtonsoft Json Deserialize Dictionary as Key/Value list from DataContractJsonSerializer]((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451990).